# Receiving data from MongoDb using React

Tags: java, reactjs, mongodb

I have been following this a tutorial online and I am able to receive data from my database. But only the data from the schema that is not part of an object. I am asking how can I receive the data from the objects as well.

```html
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;


const locationSchema = new Schema({
    Name: String,
    Address:{
        Street: {type: String},
        City: {type: String},
        Zipcode: {type: Number},
        State: {type: String},
},
    ContactInfo:{
        Email:{type:String},
        Phone:{type:Number},
    },
    Website: String,
    Hours:{
        DaysOpen: {type:[String]},
        OpeningTimes: {type:[Number]},
        ClosingTimes: {type:[Number]},
        },
    geometry: {
    type: {type: String, default:"Point"},
    coordinates: {type:[Number], index: "2dsphere"}
    },
    Services: String,
    Languages: String,
    Documentation: Boolean,
    OtherNotes: String,
})

mongoose.model('Locations', locationSchema);
```

This is my model

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const Location = props => (
  <tr>
    <td>{props.location.Name}</td>
    <td>{props.location.Website}</td>
    <td>{props.location.Services}</td>
    <td>{props.location.Languages}</td>
  </tr>
)

export default class LocationsList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.deleteLocation = this.deleteLocation.bind(this)

    this.state = {locations: []};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/location')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ locations: response.data })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  deleteLocation(id) {
    axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/location/'+id)
      .then(response => { console.log(response.data)});

    this.setState({
      locations: this.state.locations.filter(el => el._id !== id)
    })
  }

  locationList() {
    return this.state.locations.map(currentlocation => {
      return <Location location={currentlocation} deleteExercise={this.deleteLocation} key={currentlocation._id}/>;
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Logged Locations</h3>
        <table className="table">
          <thead className="thead-light">
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Website</th>
              <th>Services</th>
              <th>Languages</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            { this.locationList() }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This is how I have been receiving the data so far. How can I get out the contactinfo, Hours, address and Geometry.

I would google it and look for other solutions but idk what this would even be called.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing about mongoose is that it behaves like a general javascript object. So to get the other properties, you would just use it just like how you retrieved Name and Website. but now its nested so for like Street, it would be like: `props.location.Address.Street`

My only thing, maybe because I just don;t format my schema like this, is that i would define each property in the Schema (i.e Name, Address, etc.) using an object and within that object a Mongoose acceptable type like:

```
Name:{
  type:String
}
...
```

But if it works like that more power to ya!